# How to get better at jazz quickly?

Tags: guitar, piano, jazz

I play the piano and guitar and I'm learning to read sheet music. All I can do to make my playing sound more jazz is occasionally add flat and sharp notes that are outside the major/minor scale, play minor/major/dominant seventh chords and that's it. Anything else I try like using modes when I'm playing over backing tracks sound awful. What are some techniques that I can learn quickly that'll make my playing better.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are many, many threads here that discuss techniques for learning jazz on guitar and piano. Please search and read those. Then, if none of them provide what you need, edit your post to explain why, and it can be reopened.

Comment: @Aaron can you please provide links?

Comment: There are too many to provide individual links, but [these search results](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=jazz+learn+is%3Aquestion) will get you started.

Comment: Take a class and/or hire a teacher. There are no shortcuts. The fastest way is always private one-on-one instruction. Without that, you’ll have to take the time to piece together all the various aspects of jazz from many different free sources on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following concepts:

- [the altered scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_scale)
- [extended chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_chord)
- [four-note chord voicings](https://www.thejazzresource.com/4_note_voicings.html)
- [the 2-5-1 turnaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ii%E2%80%93V%E2%80%93I_progression)
- [tritone substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone_substitution) and [reharmonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonization#Jazz_reharmonization)

They may provide a quick way in if you just want a hack to sound jazzier without diving in too deep. These things are of course worth learning in-depth, and they will come up when you study jazz in a more formal way.

And if you want to put in more work, transcribe different versions of a few jazz standards, and try to find which details make them sound jazzy to you.

Comment: +1 for suggesting transcription. Study is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like my experience. I think the problem is first focusing on *harmony* as the principle aspect of jazz. But the *rhythmic* aspect is the more unique quality of jazz.

If you are working with modes along the lines of the "chord/scale" system, something like Jamey Abersold's methods, the first thing I would say is all the past jazz greats like Red Garland, Ahmed Jamal, Horace Silver, etc. didn't play that way. They played much more along the lines of chord tones with embellishments. If you play up and down modes in a scalar fashion, it just won't sound like those players. It's too scalar.

You didn't mention the blues scale or blue notes. Make sure you are working with the blues scale and blues style. You might think blues is separate from jazz, but they overlap and players like Horace Silver or Herbie Hancock will play bluesy riffs.

Be absolutely certain to focus on rhythm. Look up jazz swing *feel* and characteristic jazz syncopated rhythm. A lot of methods I have seen teach rhythm with simple rhythm notation (no pitch) and vocal syllables like "doo bee doo dit", or something similar. A lot of rhythm methods seems to approach this as a vocal exercise.

One thing in particular you might try to satisfy you desire to *quicky* start sounding like jazz is to stop working with the backing tracks and learn to play a walking bass in left hand while comping chords in the right hand. There are lots of method books to find for comping and it's more of a mechanical method than improvising "horn lines" on piano, so you can get up to speed in a fairly short time, at a basic level. It also provides the benefit of allowing you to develop a good sense of timing and phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to 'play what you hear'.   No-one wants to listen to you play 'the scale of the chord'.  They might be interested in how you take the melody and rhythm (and, yes, the chords, but they aren't ALL that matter) of the original song and mix them up!